# Concat values in NGINX config file for rewrite rule

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-s3

I am configuring my nginx config file `defualt.conf` for a rewrite rule to accept request and route them to S3 bucket.
           Now I am getting the content right for the later half of the URL,but I am not able to concat or prepend the url of my S3 bucket.

Here's my code:

```
  location / {
        # This code rewrites the original request, and adds the host without www in front
        # E.g. if someone requests 
        # /directory/file.ext?param=value 
        # from the coolsite.com site the request is rewritten to 
        # /coolsite.com/directory/file.ext?param=value 
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /$host_without_www$1 break;

        # The rewritten request is passed to S3
        proxy_pass http://sites.nginx.com;
    }
```

In the rewrite above I want to prepend `site.nginx.com` which is my bucket name before `/$host_without_www` i tried using `.`(dot) and unix style `{$variable_to_concat}` but did not work.
Can some one suggest me the correct way to do it.
Thank you for the attention

Comment: What is the server name of this site? Do you want fetch the content `site.nginx.com/coolsite.com/directory/file.ext?param=value` when request `/directory/file.ext?param=value`

Comment: This is the static site structure stored in s3 `sites.nginx.com(bucket name)/coolsite.com(folder name)/index.html(files)`

Comment: I got it working.actually,I had a syntax mistake for the url I tried to concat.I had to enable the debug mode for the logs and then check the values.This solved the problem! Thank you

Comment: I post another simple config, you can have a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your rewrite url matchs the hole request, you can use this simple config:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://sites.nginx.com/coolsite.com/;
}
```

Here are [some examples to show how proxy_pass maps the request url](http://www.liaohuqiu.net/nginx-proxy-pass/)

Comment: yeah, but how do you concat variables?

Comment: @Matt what do you mean by `concat`?